# When does this Deep Neural Network inequality become an equality?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, inequality

Let $\text{DNN}_k(x)$ be some fully connected DNN with $k$ hidden layers. Let $(x,y)$ be some data points and $\ell$ be a loss function.

Then $\forall  \ k \in \{1,2,,..\} $, we have that

$$\min \ell(\text{DNN}_0(x), y ) \leq  \min \ell(\text{DNN}_k(x), y )$$

My question is: $$\textbf{When does this above inequality become an equality?}$$
I have been looking at this for a while and I am not sure what to do. I am thinking about something with linear transformations? Basically, it is saying that with no activation functions, adding more hidden layers does not train a better model.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!